# is there any one explain predicate logic to this sentence Some sleepy students do not answer any question

Tags: math, artificial-intelligence, predicate, discrete-mathematics

Write a corresponding predicate logic sentences for the following
1. Some sleepy students do not answer any question

Comment: This is not a "Pleas do my job for me" platform. Try asking your question while providing what you have come up with and how you tried to solve the problem. This way more people will be inclined to help you out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not coding related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Some students do not answer any questions

> There exists a student such that for all questions the student doesn't answer the questions.

```
Exists(s).Forall(q).(not A(s, q))
```

Here, s is the student, q is the question, and A is a function which assumes the value True if student s answers question q, and the value False otherwise.